# dart task keeps on running even if vscode closed

Tags: macos, flutter, dart, apple-silicon

I don't know if that's a normal behaviour or not but a dart task always keeps running in my laptop  even if I don't have vscode open.

Device: Mackbook Air M1
[image]

sorry if it wasn't a valid question to be asked here

Answer (score 0):

you can kill dart by running using the command in your terminal

```
killall -9 dart
```